# How to read amps in a multimeter

Tags: multimeter

[image]

I don't know how to read this?

Is it 4.1A or 410 mA...?

Thanks

Comment: On what range are you and what does the manual say?

Comment: *Is it 4.1A or 410 mA* Neither, the meter is set to 200mA so both 4.1A and 410mA would then show an "overflow".

Answer (score 5):

With the probe in the 10 A socket you need to switch the meter to 10 A range. As shown in the photo your display reading is invalid.

For all other amp readings you connect the probe to the VΩmA input and select the appropriate 'm' range on the A= section.

Answer (score 0):

You can assume that the meter is using fixed point Display for the 10A range,thus the decimation point you set by the 200mA Range is displayed but the actual measurement took place by the 10A circuitry. So most probably it's 410mA. But it's kind of a trick question and the correct Answer should be "Not at all"

Answer (score -1):

You are in 200mA range. So it is 4.1mA
By the way: in this range you should use the mA receptable in the middle instead of the 10A one.

Comment: And since you're using the 10A input, the actual current isn't 4.1 mA. The meter just reads 4.1 mA but you're using it wrong so what the real current is is anyone's guess. Set the meter to the 10 A range (dial one click counterclockwise) and then read the current.

Comment: But I am running a servo in series

Comment: @AkshayGs How _else_ would you run it?

Comment: No I meant that a servo would draw a lot more than 4.1 mA ...

Comment: Sure, but you use the multimeter in a wrong way. Switch to 10A range!

Comment: @AkshayGs Because you're using the 10A socket, but switched to the 200mA range, that value (4.1) is unreliable. Keep the lead where it is and switch to the 10A range. That should give a true reading in amps. If (and only if) that value is below 200mA (shown as 0.200 or less) then you can go back to the 200m range AND move the lead to the middle socket.

Comment: @Mark, you point out he is in the wrong range so how can you be sure the reading is correct at 4.1mA as you state in your answer?

Comment: Yes I shall do that and revert asap @TripeHound

Comment: @Mark I had to give a -1 to this answer because you cannot be sure of the actual reading due to the wrong range being selected. If you edit your answer, I'll happily reverse it as you did point out the incorrect use of the meter

Comment: The question was how to read the displayed value. Not if displayed value is correct.

Comment: Mark - No, the question was about using the meter and what the displayed value meant. Quite apart from Akshay probably being in India with English as a second language, the text does not 
 support your suggestion. I very seldom downvote. I haven't here, yet. I suggest an edit.

Comment: It should require a small edit, because at the moment, although the answer points out what was wrong, it gives incorrect information, hence my downvote. If that was removed, or edited, then I am happy to change the vote. Just needs a small change, other than that, it is good